# Read data from from excel file, which is having error

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am reading excel file and storing it in Map for further use. Using below code, which is working perfect. But for some files, which shows below error when opened
[image]

**Code:**

```
private Workbook workbook;
    public Map<String,String> readMaster(Properties properties) {
    Map<String,String> masterMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
     try {
            File masterFile = new File(properties.get(ReportConstants.DCS_INPUT_PATH) + ReportConstants.DCS_MASTER_FILE);
            if(!masterFile.exists()){
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }else{
            FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(masterFile);
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
            int headItr = 0;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String key="",value="";
                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();
                int rowItr = 0;
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Some logic
}
masterMap.put(key, value);
                    }
                }

             for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : masterMap.entrySet()){  
                    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + 
                                     ", Value = " + entry.getValue()); 
            } 
            if(!masterMap.isEmpty()){
                /*FileUtility.checkDestinationDir(""+properties.get(ReportConstants.DCS_ARCHIVE_PATH));
                FileUtility.moveFile(properties.get(ReportConstants.DCS_INPUT_PATH) + ReportConstants.DCS_MASTER_FILE,
                        properties.get(ReportConstants.DCS_ARCHIVE_PATH)+ReportConstants.DCS_MASTER_FILE+FileUtility.getArchivedPattern());*/
            }else{
                EmailService.sendExceptionMail(properties.getProperty(ReportConstants.EMAIL_EXCEPTION_TO),
                        properties.getProperty(ReportConstants.EMAIL_EXCEPTION_CC),
                                " No data in master file ",
                                "DCS : Empty Master File");
                throw new Exception("No data in master file");
            } 

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("File not present while reading Master file ",e);
            EmailService.sendExceptionMail(properties.getProperty(ReportConstants.EMAIL_EXCEPTION_TO),
                    properties.getProperty(ReportConstants.EMAIL_EXCEPTION_CC),
                            " File not present while reading Master file \n\n"+e.getMessage(),
                            "DCS Report : Master File");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Input/Output Exception occured while reading Master file ",e);
            EmailService.sendExceptionMail(properties.getProperty(ReportConstants.EMAIL_EXCEPTION_TO),
                    properties.getProperty(ReportConstants.EMAIL_EXCEPTION_CC),
                            " Input/Output Exception occured while reading Master file \n\n"+e.getMessage(),
                            "DCS Report : Master File");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Genric exception occured while reading Master file ",e);
            EmailService.sendExceptionMail(properties.getProperty(ReportConstants.EMAIL_EXCEPTION_TO),
                    properties.getProperty(ReportConstants.EMAIL_EXCEPTION_CC),
                            "Exception Occurred : \n\n"+e.getMessage(),
                            "DCS Report : Master File");
        }
     finally{
         try {
                if (null!=excelFile) {
                    excelFile.close();
                }
                if(null!=workbook){
                    workbook.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }



 }
         return masterMap;
    }
```

Further I am saving details to Map and returning it for later use.
I am using:

- poi-3.13.jar
- java 1.7

Edit 1 : Added my completed method, hope it helps to replicate the issue.

Edit 2 : After clicking Yes on error pop-up message and saving it, program works fine.

Is there any way to handle this. Please suggest

Comment: Do you close the `FileInputStream` and the `workbook` at the end of your code?

Comment: I don't know if matters but maybe those files are different versions of Excel files, like xls and xlsx

Comment: @Sterconium all file's are `xlsx`

Comment: @deHaar , Yes, but no use in this case

Comment: Close both, otherwise the xml structure of the workbook gets broken.

Comment: closing both @deHaar , flow is not going inside `while` loop

Comment: Could you please show us the entire code? The entire `try`-`catch` blocks, at least...

Comment: "But for some files, which shows below error when opened ..." If that message is shown then those files are corrupt. So something must have corrupted them. Where are they coming from? How were these files created ?

Comment: @AxelRichter These files are created by other team and passed down to generate report, only files with such pop-up message are not getting read. I am finding way to handle it.

Comment: There is no general way to read corrupt files using `apache poi`. Better approach would be to avoid corrupting the files. If you click [Yes] on that message, what exactly happens then? It should tell you what exact part of the file is corrupt.

Comment: @AxelRichter After clciking [Yes], it continues and further it ask's to save the file as new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mentioned file above, I am using below snippet to read file, it returns `StreamingReader` object. it can be used further same as `Sheet`.

**Code**

```
import com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader;

public static StreamingReader getExcelSheet(File excelFile, String sheetName) throws Exception{
        StreamingReader reader = null;
        reader = StreamingReader.builder()
                .rowCacheSize(100) // number of rows to keep in memory (defaults to 10)
                .bufferSize(4096) // buffer size to use when reading InputStream to file (defaults to 1024)
                .sheetName(sheetName) // index of sheet to use (defaults to 0)
                .read(excelFile);
        return reader;
    }

StreamingReader sheet1 = FileUtility.getExcelSheet(excelFile, sheetName);   
for (Row r : sheet1){

    // iterate row here

    for (Cell cell : r) {

    //iterate cells here

    }

}
```

Hope this help's someone.